# How would I automate several delayed commands in AppleScript?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator

Let's say I want to automate the following tasks:

Send the letter "a" twice every 2 minutes

Send the letter "b" ever 30 minutes

and send the letter "C" every 1 hour.

If I make a loop with delays in it, then I won't be able to repeatedly send "a" - I can only send it once in the first 2 minute cycle, not every time.  What can I do to put together all these commands?  Do I just have to make several running scripts?

Comment: I'm not awake enough yet to write this in 'code', but a simple way is to use an integer counter & a modulo. Counter increments every minute, then if it's divisible by 2, trigger the first, if by 30 the 2nd, by 60 the 3rd.

Comment: You can also use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer) via `AppleScriptObjC` to set up some repeating timers.

Comment: @Tetsujin Indeed that is an interesting insight - I will consider it in the day ahead.

Comment: @red_ menace my experience with ObjC is very limited, but I will also look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I was able to come up with, but with a modified usage to send every 10 and 40 seconds:

```
set countTime to 0
set e to 0

    repeat while e < 42069
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "a"
            keystroke return
            if (countTime mod 40 = 0) then
                 keystroke "b"
            end if
            
        end tell
        set countTime to countTime + 10
        delay 10
        set e to e + 1
    end repeat
```

Comment: Note that in an application, a tight repeat loop like that will block its user interface.

Comment: What dost thou mean by "tight"?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you realize it but *key stokes* sent by **System Events** goes to the active *front most window* of the *front most application* and as such the target must remain *front most* and you basically cannot use the computer for anything else while the process is happening.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested under **macOS Catalina** as an **AppleScript** *stay open application*, with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

In **Script Editor**, copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code* into a new document and change `"TextEdit"` and `"Untitled"` to the appropriate values for the target *application* and *window* you want the *key stokes* to go to. The existing values were for testing purposes.

When saving, on the **Save As:** *sheet*, change **File Format:** to **[Application]**, and under **Options:** check the **[√] Stay open after run handler** *checkbox*.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property appName : "TextEdit"
property winName : "Untitled"

global theCounter

on run
    set theCounter to 0
    delay 60
end run

on idle
    my isItTimetoSendKeystroke()
    return 60
end idle

on isItTimetoSendKeystroke()
    set theCounter to theCounter + 1
    if (theCounter mod 2) = 0 then
        my sendKeystroke("a")
        my sendKeystroke("a")
    end if
    if (theCounter mod 30) = 0 then
        my sendKeystroke("b")
    end if
    if (theCounter mod 60) = 0 then
        my sendKeystroke("C")
    end if
end isItTimetoSendKeystroke

to sendKeystroke(thisKey)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process appName
            set frontmost to true
            perform action "AXRaise" of window winName
            keystroke thisKey
        end tell
    end tell
end sendKeystroke

on quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

---

**Notes:**

If you are just automating the typing of text into a text box or document, you can delete one of the `my sendKeystroke("a")` and change the other to `my sendKeystroke("aa")`, otherwise if simulating a *key* press for, say a game, then you would probably want it as it's currently coded.

**UI Scripting** can be kludgy and prone to failure.

Some *applications* will not respond to `keystroke` and or `key code` *commands* of **System Events**, as they are designed not to respond this type of *event* in this manner. **Games** are the typical type of *application* that may not respond.

Personally, I do not like this type of **UI Scripting** and have posted this more just as a proof of concept. It has been my experience that some **AppleScript** *stay open applications* can over time consume more memory and eventually crash. They can also cause the fans to spin up and maintain high RPMs. This probably has to do more so with some of the *code* being run, however, as a general rule I try to accomplish the task in a different way that does not become resource intensive, if possible.

Credit to [**Tetsujin**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) for his *comment* to the OP, which was the basis for this answer.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Nice one. I knew the theory but wouldn't have come up with this entire structure. Nicely explained caveats too.

Comment: @Tetsujin, It was late when I posted this and my **Notes:** section wasn't finished. Please see the updated notes. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was aware that AppleScript only functions on open and focused windows.  I was able to compress my function into a single loop with a countTime variable and `mod`.  Thanks for this in-depth response!

Comment: @Aaron, RE: "Yes, I was aware that AppleScript only functions on open and focused windows." --  That generalized statement is false. I was specifically talking about the `keystroke` and or `key code` _commands_ of **System Events**, not **AppleScript** in general. **AppleScript** in general is quite capable of acting on _application windows_ that are not focused nor even the _application_ focused, but not in this particular use case.  Anyway, just so you know, if you care to self-answer your question posting the _code_ you've devised, that is certainly allowed.

Comment: @user3439894 instead of using `my sendKeystroke("a")` twice, couldn’t you just use `my sendKeystroke("aa”)` ?

Comment: @wch1zpink, Only if he's typing text into a text box or document, but I assumed he's a wants to simulate pressing a key for a game. I added a note to my answer on this, thanks.

Comment: @user3439894 I was not aware of that - how would you send keystrokes or codes to a non-focused window?  I've tried using `tell process "TextEdit"` or `tell "System Events" to tell "TextEdit"`, but neither worked.

Comment: @Aaron, RE: "I was not aware of that - how would you send keystrokes or codes to a non-focused window?" --  There seems to be a communication problem! Please read again what I've precious said.

Comment: @user3439894 I see - not in this particular use case.  Thanks for your help!